# Apply CSS to a previous cell/nth cell by\via applying CSS on the current cell (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, class, styling

1. I want to apply a style using Class (preferably but not mandatory) on a prev. cell from the current cell.
2. Based on below example, I want to hide the checkbox1 (in first column) if the Type equals TypeName-1
3. Coding Restrictions,

   3.1) I can only apply CSS on any column except the first one (checkbox)column.

So based on the above restriction I need a way to **apply CSS** on ***NAME column*** AND it should **reflect** on the hide the checkbox **in the previous cell** or **first cell**!

| Check All | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| checkbox 1 | Name 1 | TypeName-1 |
| checkbox 2 | Name 2 | TypeName-2 |

**I tried,** 
[1] tbody>tr>:nth-child(cellnumber) but it does not work since the none of the elements (tbody, tr) are found in the td cell, where the css is getting applied.

[2] Just using :nth-child(1) applies to current cell, and using -ve number won't apply to previous cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there are currently no previous selector in css but there is a [next select](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp)
so a fancy hack would be to change to html and dir like this:

```
<table class="s-table" dir="rtl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Check All</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="type-1">TypeName-1</td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td class="checkbox">checkbox 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TypeName-2</td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
            <td class="checkbox">checkbox 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in css using next selector like this

```
.type-1 ~ .checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand what you say but the first col needs to be checkboxes.
(1) the checkbox has a cb-class that I can override. <p>
(2) does the below css mean, find all th having class "t1"  then only override the existing class...
th[class="t1"] .cb-class{
    visibility: visible;
}

Comment: @FamilyPhotography sorry but i didn't understand your comment question,
can you please explain?